# Test when element is visible on screen

Tags: jquery, visible

I'd like to test whether a certain div is visible on screen. Once it is visible, I'd like the divs around it to change background color.

Here is what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/4y9f2574/1/

```
if ($('.onscreen').isOnScreen()) {
    $('.box').css('background','green');
}
```

Any idea why the blue boxes aren't changing to green when the orange box is visible?

Thanks! Lauren

Comment: what is `isOnScreen()`? What element has class `.onscreen`? what element has class `.box`? Please post _all relevant code_. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, take a look at the console when things don't work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You only run your if statement once when the page is loaded. If you want it to run when you scroll the window you can do like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($('.onscreen').isOnScreen()) {
        $('.box').not('.onscreen').css('background','green');
    }
});
```

You also need to add `onscreen` to the orange box.

```
<div class="box orange onscreen"></div>
```

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4y9f2574/9/)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your fiddle with class `onscreen`. Did you mean to write `.box` instead? Like:

```
if ($('.box').isOnScreen()) {
    $('.box').css('background-color','green');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no object with class     `onscreen`

Is this you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/ez8vmbL7/1/